# Material-UI v5 Emotion error: You seem to be using a value for 'content' without quotes, try replacing it with `content: '""'`

Tags: material-ui

I migrated from Material-UI v4 to v5. Now I receive this error wherever I try to render my Material-UI-based components:

```
You seem to be using a value for 'content' without quotes, try replacing it with `content: '""'`
```

It seems to be caused by Emotion, the new style library [used](https://next.material-ui.com/guides/migration-v4/#style-library) by v5.

I found a [Github issue](https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/issues/1435#issue-469332317) for Emotion that discusses this error, but it hasn't helped me. I shouldn't have to be fiddling with how MUI uses Emotion, right? I'd expect that complexity to be hidden from me.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

[image: Screenshot of error]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I needed to change:

```
  MuiInputBase: {
    root: {
      "&:after": {
        content: "", <--------
        display: "table",
        clear: "both",
      },
    },
  },
```

to

```
  MuiInputBase: {
    root: {
      "&:after": {
        content: '""', <----------
        display: "table",
        clear: "both",
      },
    },
  },
```